# What do I need to learn to tackle the following problem: make a program that optimizes decisions in the game PlateUp!

Tags: game-ai, optimization

So, recently my friends and I have been hooked on a videogame called PlateUp!. The game is kind of a management game where the objective is to succesfully run a restaurant. The game can be roughly described as an endless loop of:

- A passive phase, in which you organize your kitchen, tools and other stuff. In this phase you also get to buy, upgrade or duplicate items, and sometimes you're forced to choose a "card" that changes some behaviour in the game.
- An active phase, in which customers show up and you must tend to them in real time and make sure they don't get tired of waiting and leave (if a single customer exceeds their impatience meter, it's game over)

My friends and I have been having fun coming up with strategies and optimizations for the game, and thought it'd be fun to try to come up with a program that plays the game and comes up with its own strategies to see what it does (mostly in the planning phase, since the active phase is more concerned with flawless execution of tasks)

So we'd like to make an AI that plays the game that makes no mistakes in the active phase (this sounds like the easy part) but also I'd like to make one that at each turn decides which debuffs to pick, which items to buy, how to organize the kitchen, etc. Its objective would then be to have the longest possible run in the game.

I've never done anything remotely close to this (most I've done related to AI is program a simple MLP and a GHA for some simple learning tasks) but I don't know how these kind of optimization problems can or should be tackled

What should I learn in order to do something like this? Specifically, the optimization part (decisions made in the planning phase) is what I'd like to tackle

Comment: reinforcement learning, and if the game is big (many possible states), then deep learning +  reinforcement learning, if instead is relatively small (no idea) you can use evolutionary algorithms